# Nextflow splitting a tuple channel with buffer

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I often generate thousands of file pairs (json and pdb) that I intend to process in smaller batches to speed up processing time. Both files are needed for a calculation.

Old channel construction:

```
Channel
  .fromPath("${params.PS_input}/*.pdb")
  .ifEmpty { error "No PDBs supplied: ${params.PS_input}" }
  .set { pdbs_in }
```

When I just needed the pdb, I used `buffer` to split the channel into chunks using this:

```
pdbs_in
  .buffer( size: 500, remainder: true )
  .set { chunked_pdbs }
```

`chunked_pdbs` channel would looked something like `[file1.pdb, file2.pdb, file3.pdb, file4.pdb, ..., file500.pdb], [file501.pdb, ...]`

However, when I feed a tuple to `buffer` I get an object I don't know how to use as input.

New channel construction:

```
Channel
  .fromFilePairs("${params.PS_input}/*{_unrelaxed_rank_001_alphafold2_multimer_v3_model_1_seed_000.pdb,_predicted_aligned_error_v1.json}")
  .ifEmpty { error "No PDB and PAE JSON pairs supplied: ${params.PS_input}" }
  .map { sample, files -> files }
  .set { pdbs_in }
```

`pdbs_in` now looks like `[file1.pdb, file1.json], [file2.pdb, file2.json], ...`
and `chunked_pdbs` now looks like `[[file1.pdb, file1.json], [file2.pdb, file2.json], ... [file500.pdb, file500.json]], [[file501.pdb, file501.json], ...]`

The process that uses the files in called `PDB_PS` and uses this input declaration:

```
input:
   tuple path(pdbs), path(json)
```

But I get the warning: `WARN: Input tuple does not match input set cardinality declared by process PDB_PS -- offending value: [[file1.pdb, file1.json], [file2.pdb, file2.json], ... [file500.pdb, file500.json]]`.

The process runs and the first two file pairs are staged correctly, but I don't see how to avoid adjusting my input declaration tuple to `tuple path(filepair1), path(filepair2), ..., path(filepair500)`, especially since the buffer size may change depending on how quickly I need the results.

I feel like there must be a solution using `map`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using the `collectFile` operator to produce a new channel that emits a single item - your "metadata.csv" file. This way, it won't matter if you have a different number of paths for your channel elements. This CSV file is then combined back with the files from the sample channel. Check the example below:

```
workflow {
    samples = Channel.of(
        ['a', [file('data/a1.bam'), file('data/a2.bam')]],
        ['b', [file('data/b1.bam'), file('data/b2.bam')]],
        ['c', [file('data/c1.bam'), file('data/c2.bam'), file('data/c3.bam')]]
    )

    samplesheet = samples | collectFile(keepHeader: true) { id, files ->  ["metadata.csv", "id,path\n" + files.collect { file -> id + ',' + file.name + '\n' }.join()] }

    samplesheet
    | combine(
        samples.flatMap{ id, files -> files }.collect().map{[it]}
    )
    | DoSomePython
}
```

This new channel can then be passed to a python process which reads the file and processes the data

```
process DoSomePython {
    input: tuple path(samplesheet), path(infiles)

    """
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import csv

    def processFile(id, path):
        f = open(path, 'r')
        print(f.readline())

    with open('$samplesheet', newline='') as csvfile:
        rowreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in rowreader:
            with open('$samplesheet', newline='') as csvfile:
                processFile(row.get('id'), row.get('path'))
    """
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm unsure how it solves the issue that I reported. I want to mix two file types and buffer them into 500 pairs of each from the thousands that are in the parent directory to parallelise the processing. 
From my understanding of your answer, it handles different size inputs, but still collects all the files into a single process.